# How to select many values with the same ID in one table in SQL

Tags: sql, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I've tried for hours, but still not receive the result as expected.

I have Table A that contains the Customer ID and Product Name. I would like to write an SQL to find the customers who have purchased Product A but have not purchased Product C

Table A:

| Customer ID | Product Name |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | A |
| 001 | B |
| 001 | C |
| 002 | A |
| 002 | B |
| 003 | A |
| 003 | C |
| 004 | A |
| 005 | B |
| 006 | C |

Expected outcome:

| Customer ID | Product Name |
| --- | --- |
| 002 | A |
| 002 | B |
| 004 | A |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 create table TableA(Customer_ID varchar(10),   Product_Name varchar(10));
 insert into TableA values('001'    ,'A');
 insert into TableA values('001'    ,'B');
 insert into TableA values('001'    ,'C');
 insert into TableA values('002'    ,'A');
 insert into TableA values('002'    ,'B');
 insert into TableA values('003'    ,'A');
 insert into TableA values('003'    ,'C');
 insert into TableA values('004'    ,'A');
 insert into TableA values('005'    ,'B');
 insert into TableA values('006'    ,'C');
```

Query#1 (using in):

```
 select * from TableA 
 where customer_id in (select customer_id from TableA where product_name='A')
 and customer_id not in (select customer_id from TableA where product_name='C')
```

| Customer_ID | Product_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 002 | A |
| 002 | B |
| 004 | A |

Query#2 (using exists):

```
 select * from TableA A
 where exists (select 1 from TableA B where product_name='A' and A.customer_id=B.customer_id) 
 and not exists (select 1 from TableA C where product_name='C' and A.customer_id=C.customer_id)
```

Output:

| Customer_ID | Product_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 002 | A |
| 002 | B |
| 004 | A |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=42781513e4fe3419b08aaca982eca171)*

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I've tried to apply 'IN' and 'NOT IN' to my code, but they did not work. On the other hand, my code has worked since I applied 'EXIXTS' and 'NOT EXISTS' to it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE ProductName = 'A' 
      AND CustomerID NOT IN (SELECT CustomerID 
                             FROM A 
                             WHERE ProductName = 'C');
```

I use a subquery to get Customer IDs who purchased product C and exclude them from the result.

Answer (score 2):

If you have only one row per product/customer, use `not exists`:

```
select customer
from t
where product = 'A' and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.customer = t.customer and t2.product = 'C');
```

This could return duplicates if customer/product rows are duplicated.

An alternative is to use aggregation:

```
select customer
from t
where product in ('A', 'C')
group by customer
having min(product) = max(product) and min(product) = 'A';
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Select from table where product equal A or B
2. Left join to table on customer where product equals C
3. Add WHERE left joined product is null

Answer (score 1):

This would do the job

```
select * from TableA
where Customer_ID not in
    (select distinct Customer_ID
    from TableA
    where Product_Name = 'C')
and Customer_ID in
    (select distinct Customer_ID
    from TableA
    where Product_Name = 'A')
```